# Не могу получить все линки матчей онлайн из href, ограничивает 15 ссылками

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/live/Football/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'
      }


all_hrefs = []  # Тут я буду хранить наши хрефы!
    # Загружаю страницу
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Забираю себе хрефы и очищаем их
hrefs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "c-events__item c-events__item_col"})
clean_hrefs = [item.a.attrs['href'] for item in hrefs]
all_hrefs.extend(clean_hrefs)
print('Колличество Матчей =', len(all_hrefs))
print('\nhttps://1xstavka.ru/'.join(all_hrefs))

#дерево
with open('test.html', 'w' , encoding='UTF-8') as output_file:
  output_file.write(response.text)
```

Comment: У меня сложилось стойкое впечатление, что все сайты с матчами делаются с упором на javascript, а для этого нужен движок на js. Посмотрите что пришло от сайта `print(soup)` и проверьте, что нужные вам теги там. Если их нет, то используйте, например, `selenium`

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня уже был подобный вопрос. [Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' в парсере на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185452/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/1185542#1185542)

Данные подгружает скрипт. Вот этот код загрузит страницу, подождет 5 сек, пока сработают скрипты и потом сохраняет страницу. Потом можно распарсить супом. 50 ссылок выдает.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import csv


# в этой части работает selenium
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://1xstavka.ru/live/Football/')
time.sleep(5)
main_page = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page, "html.parser")
browser.close()

all_hrefs = []
hrefs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "c-events__item c-events__item_col"})

clean_hrefs = [item.a.attrs['href'] for item in hrefs]
all_hrefs.extend(clean_hrefs)
print('Колличество Матчей =', len(all_hrefs))
print('\nhttps://1xstavka.ru/'.join(all_hrefs))



all_hrefs = []
hrefs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': "c-events__item c-events__item_col"})

clean_hrefs = [item.a.attrs['href'] for item in hrefs]
all_hrefs.extend(clean_hrefs)
print('Колличество Матчей =', len(all_hrefs))
print('\nhttps://1xstavka.ru/'.join(all_hrefs))
```

Вот тут можно скачать подходящий chrome driver.https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads Можно и другие использовать, firefox например.

Comment: Супер. спасибо.помогло. двигаюсь дальше в изучении

Comment: однако все равно упирается в 50 линков, необходимо как то пройти по <li  class

Comment: Ну так естественно что упирается в 50. Потому что только 50 отображаются на главной странице. Остальное нужно парсить в других местах.

Comment: Спасибо, чуть позже начну перебирать суп по li, уже нашёл от куда, поделюсь позже успехами и проблемами)